# laravel submit Get form

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5.3

i have following code

In View

```
      <form method="get" action="{{url('/submit-model')}}" class="form-horizontal form-label-left"  id="">
<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{!! csrf_token() !!}" />
<div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Select Brand</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

                            <select id="select_brand" class="select_brand   form-control show-tick" data-live-search="true" name="brand_name">

            @foreach($brandList as $key=>$val)

              <option value="{{$val->id}}" >{{$val->brand_name}}-{{$val->id}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Select Model</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <select id="select_model" class="select_model show-tick form-control" data-live-search="true" name="model_name"  >


        </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  <!--  <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Select Model</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

                          <input id="brand_name" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" 
                           name="brand_name" id="brand_name"
                                                   placeholder="Brand Name e.g Nokia"  type="text" value="">




        </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>--->
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

                          <button id="send" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Search</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </form>
```

In route

```
 Route::get('mobiteam/submit-model/', 'MobiTeamController@submitModel');
```

In Controller

```
  public function submitModel(Request $request){

       print_r($request->all());
}
```

My question is

1. how i can submit get form using user friendly url like

   Route::get('/submit-model/{brandName}/{modelName}', 'MobiTeamController@submitModel');

instead of

```
http://localhost/project/public/submit-model?_token=4LsaeqXbsjWLYf199LtSr7EgLacxhncNKde9Zpy2&brand_name=39&model_name=21
```

In ajax i can but i am trying  without ajax

Comment: Use `POST` instead of `GET`?

Comment: if i use post user cant come back to previous url

Answer (score 3):

You would submit to another method and redirect to your route with params.

Generally you'd do something like this:

**1st: Create a new route:**

```
    // modify your route to:
    Route::get('mobiteam/submit-model/{param1}/{param2}', [
      'as' => 'mobiteam',
      'uses' => 'MobiTeamController@submitModel'
    ]);

   // add a new route:
    Route::get('redirect-with-params', [
     'as' => 'redirect',
     'uses' => 'MobiTeamController@redirectWithParams'
    ]);
```

**2nd: Submit to the previously created route (replace the old action with  *redirect* as followed):**

```
<form method="get" action="{{route('redirect'}}" class="form-horizontal form-label-left"  id="">
```

**3nd: create the method and redirect with params:**

```
// MobiTeamController.php
public function redirectWithParams(Request $request){
  return \Redirect::route('mobiteam', ['param1' => $request->param1, 'param2' => $request->param2]);
}
```

That's it!

Comment: Thanks Waiyl karim.

Comment: Sure, glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

This is not a common request, but you can build `action` by yourself:

```
<form method="get" action="/submit-model/{{ $brand }}/"...>
```

You get the point. But @Waiyl's answer is cleaner.

Comment: Thanks Jakub for the answer

Answer (score 0):

The simple way for the following types of URLs
http://app.test/app/search?field1=foo&field2=bar

For me it was that I had id instead of name at the input field!

1. Blade

```
<form action="{{ route('searchRoute') }}" method="GET">
  <input name="field1" type="text" />
  <input name="field2" type="text" />
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

2. web.php

```
Route::get('/app/search', [\App\Http\Controllers\AppController::class, 'searchRoute'])
     ->name('searchRoute');
```

3. AppController.php

```
public function searchRoute(Request $request)
{
  //Access variables
  //$request->all();
  //$request->input('field1');
  //$request->input('field2');
  //return ...
}
```